find element's coordinates in pdf node.js
I have html file that I convert it to pdf file by html-pdf library. I have a div element in my file and I need his coordinates after the converting.
this is my code to convert:
 async generatePDFfromHtml(html,pdfName,pdfPath){

        const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            pdf.create(html, options).toFile(path.resolve(`${pdfPath}/${pdfName}.pdf`), function(err, res) {

                if (!err) { resolve(res.filename);  return;}
                reject(null); console.log(err) 
        })
      });
      return promise
    }

}


I see that I can find a text in pdf but I don't know how to find element
